# How to fetch the viewid from google analytics by giving the access_token using python

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-filters

After successful login from the consent screen, I am getting the access_token now the next step is to fetch all the view id from the google analytics account.Please help me out

Example: This is the access_token("ya29.A0ARrdaM8IvLg8jjVHWgxneSp_mxgFYHpKt4LwPGZEVqzOphMA2Cll6mjMxlQRFanbJHh1WrBEYVe2Y1BvBU6j7h_17nVeY4h-FWdUuv5bo0rzETTz_-xw4t5ZNBYpj26Cy3u4Y1trZnqVIA4")

Comment: Try the managment api it gives you access to the Google analtyics account it self.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Managment api quickstart python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/installed-py)

```
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools


def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, client_secrets_path):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: string The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: string The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list of strings representing the auth scopes to authorize for the
      connection.
    client_secrets_path: string A path to a valid client secrets file.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      client_secrets_path, scope=scope,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(client_secrets_path))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage(api_name + '.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for the authorized user.
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
    properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=account).execute()

    if properties.get('items'):
      # Get the first property id.
      property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=account,
          webPropertyId=property).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions in the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, 'client_secrets.json')
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```